# Is it possible to drive led strips using a halogen driver?

Tags: led, light, halogen

I have a 12v halogen setup in my kitchen which I'm looking to replace with 12v led strips. I have everything working and the light strips work, until I unplug the halogen lamps at which point the leds start turning on and off very slowly. Is it something like there isn't enough load?

Comment: [changing 12v halogen lighting to 12v LED](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/330366/27928)  , 
[Efficiency of Halogen lamp Transformer when used with LED lamps](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/98765/27928)

Answer (score 2):

Your power supply doesn't like the LEDs.  That's not a surprise. Either

- because there isn't enough current flowing (the halogen acted as a dummy resistor to create some load), in which case more load will cure the problem.  Or
- the power supply needs to be able to leak current in both directions (AC) through the light. Halogens can do that, LEDs cannot.  Try reversing the polarity on some of your LED strips.  If they still light and it solves the problem, that's actually bad news - it means this power supply is outputting AC and it's not fit for LED strips. (not least it will make them shimmer at 60Hz, which will be very noticeable and much worse than 120Hz shimmer from obsolete fluorescents).  It's time to replace this power supply with a DC supply, that will both work with LEDs *with no shimmer whatsoever*, and also support halogens.